# Unable to compile and link with openssl with cmake on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, openssl

I am trying to make my code compile on Windows, and read since a couple of days all opened discussions on **stackoverflow** on the subject, without finding a solution.

I installed `openssl` with `choco` in a terminal with privileges:

```
choco install openssl -y
```

and I notice that it gets installed to `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`.

Here is the content of the `openssl` directory:

```
 dir "$OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR"
acknowledgements.txt  authors.txt  bin  c_rehash.pl  changes.txt  exp  faq.txt  include  lib  libcrypto-3-x64.dll  libssl-3-x64.dll  license.txt  news.txt  readme.txt  start.bat  tests  unins000.dat  unins000.exe
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have this relevant line:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

Nothing very special here. And of course, it cannot be that easy:

```
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found
  version "3.2.1")
```

So, I deleted the CMake cache, add the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` in my `PATH`, restarted the shell, make sure that my variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` is correctly set, re-launch `cmake`, and same error.

I use `cmake 3.28.3` and `openssl` version installed is `3.2.1`.

In GitHub actions the `openssl` library is installed by default for runner `windows-latest`, and cmake can find it directly.
However, I have the exact similar issue for `curl`, if I install it manually and provide the correct variables to `cmake`, it cannot find `curl`.

It works out of the box on my `Ubuntu` system, just installing `libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssl-dev`, I don't need to care about setting any variable whatsoever. And it worked also on GitHub actions before the latest `windows-latest` runner last week.

Comment: Can you try something like `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/path/to/openssl ...`?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes, tried that as well. It does not change anything. Also, I made sure by `echo $OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` that my variable is correctly set.

Comment: Does your openssl directory contain libcrypto? CMake doesn't seem to find libcrypto in that directory.

Comment: I just updated the description adding the contents of `openssl` root directory. It contains `libcrypto-3-x64.dll`

Comment: Maybe you should also raise an issue in OpenSSL's Github repo, just in case.

Comment: Run `cmake` with additional option `--debug-find`. That way CMake will print paths which are checked for find specific libraries. From such output you could find out which paths are checked for find the library corresponding to `OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY`.

Comment: Try updating to `cmake` 3.29.0. I got the same error and upgrading appears to resolve. The issue may be addressed by https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25702.